# How to set `org-agenda-files` depending current date in order to lessen number of files to load?

Tags: org-agenda, regular-expressions, org-roam

I use `org-roam-dailies` for my TODO lists for given day. And currently, I set my `org-agenda-files` to `org-roam-dailies`'s directory as below:

```
  (setq org-agenda-files  '("~/roamnotes/daily/"))
```

**Problem**: as my number of daily entries increasing, `org-agenda` is loading all my entries in the directory above, resulting quite some time lag.

**Possible Fix**: For me, I don't need to load entries that's older than 2 or more week, (and also 2 weeks in the future). Less files to open = faster `org-agenda`.  Daily entries have filename format `yyyy-mm-dd.org` (e.g. `2022-11-09.org`). So I'm guessing that with some regular-expression tricks this can be achieved.

**Question**: How to make `org-agenda` to load entries that is within ±2 weeks time windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a function that you can use:

```el
;;; -*- lexical-binding: t -*-

(defun my/filter-org-roam-dailies (dir ndays-before ndays-after)

  "Filter the list of files in DIR that have a `.org' suffix. They are all
 supposed to have names of the form \"YYYY-MM-DD.org\". We only
 accept those whose names have a date part that falls within the
 date range `<today> - NDAYS-BEFORE' and `<today> + NDAYS-AFTER',
 inclusive of the ends dates."

  ;; This "inner" function finds the "free" variables `ndays-before' and
  ;; `ndays-after' in the lexical environment, in this case the
  ;; arguments of the "outer" function
  (cl-flet ((my/pred-org-roam-dailies (filename)
    "Check if the FILENAME qualifies for inclusion."
    (let ((fname-date (file-name-sans-extension (file-name-nondirectory filename)))
          (date-min (format-time-string "%Y-%m-%d" (time-add nil (* -86400 (+ 1 ndays-before)))))
          (date-max (format-time-string "%Y-%m-%d" (time-add nil (* 86400 (+ 1 ndays-after))))))
      ;; if the date corresponding to the name of the file falls between date-min
      ;; and date-max, return the (complete) filename
      (when (and (string<  date-min fname-date) (string< fname-date date-max))
        filename))))
    ;; end of inner function

    ;; the "outer" function maps the above predicate on the list of files
    ;; with a ".org" suffix in the given DIRectory and returns the
    ;; filtered list (after deleting nil entries).
    (delq nil
          (mapcar #'my/pred-org-roam-dailies (directory-files dir t "\\.org\\'")))))
```

Save the above in a file, load the file and then you can use the function like this:

```el
(setq org-agenda-files (my/filter-org-roam-dailies "~/roamnotes/daily/" 14 14)
```

Check the value of `org-agenda-files` afterwards (with `C-h v org-agenda-files`) to make sure you got everything you wanted.

You will have to recalculate `org-agenda-files` every day however: there is no automation for that in this answer.

EDIT: Fixed the regexp in the `directory-files` call to match only `.org` files. This is the same regexp as the one used in `auto-mode-alist`, so it should be correct, but it's only lightly tested at this point.

Comment: Thanks dude ! This Rocks

Comment: This seems accepting the emacs backup for each org-files. (both `2023-04-04.org` & `2023-04-04.org~` loaded.) How to exclude files that are ends with `~`?

Comment: Fixed the regexp to do that. Thanks for the heads-up! I should have seen that coming :-)

Comment: Thanks @NickD, This is working perfectly